# How to create protobuf instances using java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, inner-classes, protocol-buffers

Normally you create an protobuf class instance like this:

```
Bar.Builder bld = Bar.newBuilder();
bld.setXYZ(...
```

I have a usecase that uses the Java reflection to instantiate a protobuf class:

```
Class clsBar = Class.forName("com.xyz.Foo$Bar");
Object instance = clsBar.newInstance(); // error here!
Method mth = clsBar.getMethod(...);
```

The above code works fine with normal Java classes.  But for a generated protobuf class `"com.xyz.Foo$Bar"`, It gives me an `NoSuchMethodException`, as there isn't a default public constructor there.

Any suggestions on how to use Java refection to create protobuf instances?  The question is for someone who's really good at protobuf internals.  Thank!

Comment: What if you called clsBar.getConstructors() and called the .newInstance() method on one of the Constructor objects that's returned?

Comment: What Information do you have at hand? Only the desired class or more? If you want to create a Protobuf instance from a byte array or similar you could use the `parseFrom` method.

Comment: @Duston All the constructors are private, as the protobuf implementation goes.  To dpr, I only have the full qualified class names that are generated protobuf classes.

Comment: Ah, I read that as not having a public constructor that takes no arguments.  Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should go the full way: through the Builder class:

```
//get Bar class
Class barClass = Class.forName("com.xyz.Foo$Bar");

//instantiate Builder through newBuilder method
Method newBuilderMethod = barClass.getMethod("newBuilder");
Bar.Builder builder = (Bar.Builder) newBuilderMethod.invoke(null);

// ... set properties  -- can be through reflection if necessary

//build:
Bar bar = builder.build();
```

Though I don't exactly see how reflection is of any use in this case, that would probably require a deeper understanding of the exact problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Your answer is in the right direction, but with a minor error: "newBuilder" method belongs to 'Bar' class, not 'Bar$Builder'. Thanks!